# Update a module and "is outside" error

Tags: 7, updating

I have a new installation of Drupal 7.52 on a Windows server and during the update of some modules I receive that `/websites/mydrupalroot/....` is outside from `/website/mydrupalroot`!

I found this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701991/drupal-module-installation-error-file-transfer-failed-reason-mysite-com-site

but the solution didn't work for me!
What could be the problem?
Could it be the directories privileges?

Comment: When do you get the message you mentioned (Running cron, every page load, etc)?

Comment: Did you tried solution provided on ref link in that question _[Can't install Modules on Drupal 7 (IIS)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1071870#comment-8507091)_.

Comment: @Yogesh  yes but these didn't work! The path is already relative and the code added didn't work for me!

Comment: @acrosman  I have this problem when I try to update all modules after the correct download of the modules.

Comment: It sounds like you have been using the update tool within Drupal. Have you tried updating the modules one at a time manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the solution mentioned in the link included in your question, here are a few other things you may want to try:

- Temporary change the configuration of the file system used by Drupal, to use a relative path to the temp folder (eg `..\temp`) instead of a full path (eg `C:\path\to\your\webroot\temp`).
- In your question it says "*... during the update of some modules...*", but nowhere you explained HOW you're performing this update. Are you using the update tool within Drupal? Are you using Drush? Are you performing this update using FTP or something like that? Whichever method you use, try to use any of the other typical approaches for updating modules. While doing so, you may run into some other unexpected problem/message, which may actually give you a clue about what your real problem is. E.g. some problem with a tmp-like folder to just unpack the new version of the module.
- Try to disable *all* your modules first, then re-enable one of them again, and apply all updates, if any, related to that module you just enabled. If for this first module the error doesn't come back, you've reduced the list of modules that cause your proble with one. If the error does come back, disable that module again (to be investigated in more detail afterwards). Repeat for each of your other modules. This approach should help you to find/identify the problem module (and either leave that disabled, or start in depth debugging of that module).

Comment: @pierre-vriens thanks for your answer! I accepted because it is very clear but I can't try the solutions that you gave me for today! However, I try to update the module from update tool inside drupal, I will try the other method soon!